# Dynamic file in request body

Tags: file, request, karate

I am playing with Karate to test one resource that accepts a date that cannot be in the past.

```
Scenario: Schedule one
    Given path '/schedules'
    And request read('today_at_19h30.json')
    When method post
    Then status 201
```

I have created some JSON files (mostly duplicates but with subtle changes) for each scenario. But I cannot seriously imagine changing the date in all of them each time I want to run my tests.

Using a date in the far future is not a good idea because there is some manual verification and that will force us to click (on next) too many times.

Is there a way to include a variable or an expression in a file?

Thanks

Comment: can you edit the question and clarify if you are talking binary files ? for text, json or xml files this will be very easy

Comment: Done. It is JSON because this is the format expected by the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to "clobber" JSON data in Karate. One way is to just use a JS expression. For example:

```
* def foo = { a: 1 }
* foo.a = 2
* match foo == { a: 2 }
```

For your specific use case, I suspect [embedded expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions) will be the more elegant way to do it. The great thing about embedded expressions is that they work in combination with the [`read()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files) API.

For example where the contents of the file `test.json` is `{ "today": "#(today)" }`

```
Background:
* def getToday =
"""
function() {
  var SimpleDateFormat = Java.type('java.text.SimpleDateFormat');
  var sdf = new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy/MM/dd');
  var date = new java.util.Date();
  return sdf.format(date);
}
"""

Scenario:
* def today = getToday()
* def foo = read('test.json')
* print foo
```

Which results in:

```
Running com.intuit.karate.junit4.dev.TestRunner
20:19:20.957 [main] INFO  com.intuit.karate - [print] {
  "today": "2020/01/22"
}
```

By the way if the `getToday` function has been defined, you can even do this: `{ "today": "#(getToday())" }`. Which may give you more ideas.

Comment: Thanks. It was described in the documentation but I missed it. Is there a way to skip the function definition and have `def today = """ /* Create a format date */ """` ?

Comment: @gervais.b kind of, you can define re-usable functions like this: https://github.com/intuit/karate#multiple-functions-in-one-file - and once you get familiar with `karate-config.js` you can even attempt to init them "globally" instead of a one-liner in each feature where you need it, but I don't particularly recommend that extreme re-use, YMMV